# writing Regex to exteract words from text in Java

Tags: java, regex

I  writing a program in Java using regex ,i have many structure for the sentence 
 Given string; "book 'learning java' for doctor  ahmed mohamed ". or" the best title: learning java for ahmed mohamed ", and so on ...,

meaning that:

(book) may be [the book or text: or (text)].

(for doctor  ) may be [ for author or for or by for doctor].

the output:

I want to extract any words after (book) and before (for doctor  ) and named it Title.
And extract any words after (for doctor  ) and named it Author.

```
String inputtext =  "book 'learning java' for doctor  ahmed mohamed";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=(book| the book| \\( . \\)|\\:)) .*? (?=(for doctor| for| for author))");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputtext);


        if (m.matches()) {
        String author = m.group(1).trim();
        String bookTitle = m.group(2).trim();

        System.out.println("Title is : " + author);
        System.out.println("Author is : " + bookTitle);
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: please answer this question

Comment: how to write the expression in( pattern p) and  (pattern pa)?

Comment: It's indeed not clear what the question is.. frankly, I can't even understand the meaning of the post fully..

Comment: The problem might be that most readers here probably don't understand the post because the input text as well as the patterns use arabic text - which is hard to decipher for those that are not familiar with the language, especially due to its RTL nature. Could you provide an example using english letters for the input string as well as your expressions?

Comment: Please provide a compilable example using english characters, including input text and expected output. It's still hard to understand your requirements.

Comment: You say `(book) may be [the book or text: or (text)]` but you still have an example that wouldn't match that rule: `the best title: learning java for ahmed mohamed`. Is there a fixed syntax that will be used or are the following possible as well: `'learning java' by ahmed mohamed`, `ahmed mohamed: learning java` etc. ? - If the latter is the case, it might be quite hard to correcly extract the title and author correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and provide a hint, but since I can't read your expression I just can guess.

So your expression is this:

```
(?<=(للدكتورة|للعلامه|للشيخ|للكاتب |للكاتبه|للامام|للاستاذ|للقاضى|للدكتور|ل ))\s[^\s]+\s[^\s]+
```

In a break down it would look like this:

- positive look behind for `(?<=(للدكتورة|للعلامه|للشيخ|للكاتب |للكاتبه|للامام|للاستاذ|للقاضى|للدكتور|ل ))`
- a whitespace character followed by some word
- a whitespace character followed by some word

Basically the match would then be any sequence that contains 2 whitespace - word combinations and is preceeded by any of the words in your match.

This seems to be your actual problem, as you stated:

> this expression give me only 2 word

A possible solution would be to match more than 2 words and maybe even more that one whitespace. So after your look behind, try this: `(?>\s+[^\s]+)+` instead of `\s[^\s]+\s[^\s]+`. This part should match any sequence of whitespace followed by non-whitespace, e.g. (in english letters) it would match `aaa bbb` as well as `aaa   bbb     ccc   ddd` (HTML won't display multiple whitespace here, but imagine the gaps where larger than just one space).

Comment: Please see  Regex in pattern p and replay what changes in this pattern to give me string between two sides.

Comment: @ShimaaMohamed could you _please_ provide an example of your problem using english letters? Those LTR-RTL switches in your expression drive me nuts and it makes understanding the actual expression very hard (which is first, which is last etc.).

Comment: I convert that i want in English